# Link Public Github Repo on Bintray to JCenter

Tags: publish, bintray, jcenter

I'm trying to publish https://bintray.com/mvysny/github/com.github.kaributesting onto JCenter, but the process fails with "Failed to send a message: The version control git returns 404.". Any tips on this please? Bintray, could you please make your error messages a bit more specific?

Answer (score 3):

The reason was that I simply had "git" stated in the `Version control` field. The field's hint says it should be URL but the field is not validated, so `git` was accepted. I think it's supposed to point to the sources of the project. When I changed that to `https://github.com/mvysny/karibu-testing` it worked.

Comment: In my case the culprit was `sbt-bintray` plugin that I used to release the package. I tried changing the url to start with `git://git@gitlab.com` and that worked ... I'm wondering whether that is a bad idea though (should it start with https as you said)?